# Slow MSSQL data loading in PyQT5 tableWidget

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

I am creating a GUI app with PyQt5 and MSSQL as a database server. i am able to connect MSSQL server within 2 seconds easily but while i load the data with a simple select query it takes 10 seconds, which normally takes 2 sec max.i am not getting where i did wrong with my code.

my code strucure :

1. main.py (which is generated from .ui)
2. connection.py (database connection)
3. mainApp.py (where tablewidget,signal slot are inherit)
4. data_handler (loading data/ sql queries)

**connection.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication,QMessageBox, QLabel
import sys

USERNAME = '********'
PASSWORD = '******'
DATABASE = ''

def selectedServer(server):
    switcher = {
        'Server 1': '1**.1*.7*.1*,1433',
        'Server 2': '1**.1*.7*.1*,1433',
    }
    return switcher.get(server, "Invalid Server ")

def createConnection(self, server):

    SERVER = selectedServer(server)
    global db
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC')
    db.setDatabaseName(f'Driver={{SQL SERVER}}; Server={SERVER}; UID={USERNAME}; PWD={PASSWORD};')
    if db.open():
        print(f'{server} Server connected successfully')
        QMessageBox.about(self, 'Connection',f'{server} Server connected successfully')
        return True
    else:
        print(f'{server} connection failed')
        return False
#loading data---------------
def loadData(query_string):
  
    query = QSqlQuery(db)
    res = query.exec(query_string)
    record = query.record()
    column_number= record.count()
    
    header_list=[]
    for i in range(column_number):
        header_list.append(record.field(i).name())
    result_list = []

    while query.next():
        sublist =[]
        for i in range(column_number):
            sublist.append(query.value(i))
        result_list.append(sublist)
    
    return [header_list,result_list]
```

**data_handler.py**

```
    from connection.connection import *
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    from  PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    
    def loadInsightAccount(input_value,type_value):
    
         if type_value=="AccountID":
            print("True")
            
            query_string="SELECT convert(int,iinsightaccountid) as AccountID,* from AccountMaster.dbo.Accounttable(nolock) where iinsightAccountID="+input_value
            print(query_string)
            InsightAcc_data=loadData(query_string)
    
            header_list = InsightAcc_data[0]
            value_list =  InsightAcc_data[1]
            # print(header_list)
            # print(value_list)
    
            return (InsightAcc_data)
```

**mainApp.py**

```
def insightAccountCall(self):
                print("Loading insight Account datas...")    
                
                input_value=self.account_lineEdit.text()
                type_value=str(self.account_comboBox.currentText())
               
                accountData2=loadInsightAccount(input_value,type_value)
        
                header_list = accountData2[0]
                value_list =  accountData2[1]
               
                no_rows = len(value_list)
                no_columns= len(header_list)
        
               
                self.tableWidget_accInfo.setRowCount(no_rows) 
                self.tableWidget_accInfo.setColumnCount(no_columns)
        
                self.tableWidget_accInfo.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(tuple(header_list))
                self.tableWidget_accInfo.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
                self.tableWidget_accInfo.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
                self.tableWidget_accInfo.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
                self.tableWidget_accInfo.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
                
            
                self.tableWidget_accInfo.setSortingEnabled(True)
                self.tableWidget_accInfo.resizeRowsToContents()
                self.tableWidget_accInfo.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorChanged.connect(self.tableWidget_accInfo.resizeRowsToContents)
                self.tableWidget_accInfo.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows) #full row  select
                self.tableWidget_accInfo.setRowHeight(0, 10)
                self.tableWidget_accInfo.resizeColumnsToContents()
        
            
                for row in range(no_rows):
                    for col in range(no_columns):
                        self.tableWidget_accInfo.setItem(row,col,QTableWidgetItem(str(value_list[row][col])))
```

Comment: Use a [QSqlQueryModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html) with a `QTableView`. Loading it all in python with for-loops etc is always going to be much slower, no matter how you do it.

Comment: thanks a lot @ekhumoro  ,  i am now able to load data with QsqlQueryModel with QTableView.
How can i show in my  'tableWidget' which i already design in mainWindow.py

Comment: You cannot use `QSqlQueryModel` with a `QTableWidget`, so you must replace it with a `QTableView`. The `QTableWidget` class inherits [`QTableView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html), so it is mostly the same, but without some convenience methods.

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro, please see in answer part. i have recreated .ui fileand updated QTableWidget to QTableView. now i am not able to return the dataset. i know , i did bad. i am quite new in Pyqt5. please help me out.

how to return the dataset and show in tableView?

Comment: Set the model on the view ***once*** during setup, and then set a new query on the model to display the selected data. Don't keep re-creating the model and view. Just do `self.tableView.model().setQuery(qry)`. If you want to understand more, see [Model/View Programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) in the Qt Docs.